# Slick2d and AWT fonts rendering weirdly

Tags: java, fonts, awt, slick2d

I am currently working on a Slick2D project and fonts are really bothering me. I figured out how to loas them properly (I think ?) but it's not rendering that nice on screen.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkWUN.png) is what I would like to get, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw77B.png) is what I actually get.
Also, here is the corresponding code for loading the font :

```
import org.newdawn.slick.TrueTypeFont;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public final class SlickGraphicsConstants {

    public static final TrueTypeFont BIG_FONT = loadFont("freestylescript.ttf", Font.PLAIN, 50);

    private static TrueTypeFont loadFont(String name, int style, int size) {
        InputStream is = ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(name);
        try {
            Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            f = f.deriveFont(style, (float) size);
            return new TrueTypeFont(f, true);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me for this one please ?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hot-link to the font. 2) BTW - what happens if the code renders the `Font` as opposed to the `TrueTypeFont`? 3) See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) (Point: Don't include swathes of redundant white space, as seen in the 2nd image.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your response and advice ! I just found myself a solution by switching to a `UnicodeFont` rather than a `TrueTypeFont`. Thank you anyway !